# Refresh single worksheet (excel) in workbook using xlwings

Tags: python, excel, refresh, xlwings

I looked around a bit but could not find an answer. I found RefreshAll() which is not what I want to do.

Say I have a workbook named "DATA" with following sheets, "Forecast Temps", "Actual Temps", "Table", "Summary".

Now imagine that Forecast Temps sheet has a time series function that grabs data from NWS. This worksheet needs to be refreshed and then temps added into specified column in worksheet "Table". After this, Sheet Summary can be refreshed to determine new high and lows for that day.

Yes - I could run RefreshAll() at each step, but this seems redundant and would take the script longer to run. I was wondering if there was a way to refresh a single sheet w/ xlwings.

I also know you can do it in VBA, but my plan is to write a python script and then create a Sub where I call RunPython ("ScriptName").

Would I be able to do something like:

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book("path")
forecast_temps = wb.sheet[0]
summary = wb.sheet[1]

forecast_temps.refresh() #do not know the correct func here (if there is one)?
```

Answer (score 0):

I think RefreshAll() is not part of xlwings API. You may call the Excel API like this: wb.api.RefreshAll().

If you know how to do it in VBA, the same will probably work in xlwings using .api. I think you will have some kind of workbook connection. wb.api.Connections should return a list of all workbook connections. From there you can go on with the [WorkbookConnection-Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbookconnection), which have a Refresh() method.